# What is the moduli space $M _{0,5}$?

Tags: projective-space, moduli-space, projective-varieties

Let $M_{0,n}$ denote the moduli space which consists of genus 0 non singular projective curves with n distinct marked points upto marked point isomorphism.

So $M_{0,3}$ is a singleton set as any 3 points on $\mathbb P^1$ can be mapped to ${0,1,\infty }$ via an automorphism.

Similarly, $M_{0,4}$ can be identified with $\mathbb P^1-\{{0,1, {\infty \} }}$ as the first 3 marked points can be sent to $0,1,\infty$ and the 4th point can be mapped to any other point.

> What is $M_{0,5}$?

> What is
> $\overline M _{0,5}$? (The Kontsevich Compactification which consists of nodal singular genus 0 projective curves with n distinct marked points upto marked point isomorphism with finite automorphism group)

Here also we can send first 3 points to $0,1,\infty$ but what shall we do about the rest 2 points?

Comment: Sorry, but what course is this from?

Comment: I am currently reading a paper by Fulton and Pandharipande (Notes on Stable Maps and Quantum Cohomology). It uses these moduli spaces and I'm trying to understand them.

Comment: You have $M_{0, 5} = \{(p, q) \in (M_{0, 4})^2 \mid p \neq q\}$, and $\overline{M}_{0, 5}$ is the blow-up of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ at the points $(0,0)$, $(1, 1)$ and $(\infty, \infty)$. For more details you can refer to/read say [these lecture notes](https://anddil.github.io/_pages/CohFT/Lecture1.pdf) and [this paper](https://www.hse.ru/data/2014/11/13/1101420183/2013.04.03.pdf).

Comment: @rushy Could you make that into an answer, preferably adding details regarding the links? :)

Answer (score 4):

For the moduli space $M_{0, 5}$, you can take a similar approach as for $M_{0, 4}$. Note that any curve $(C, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)$ with $5$ marked points is isomorphic to a curve of the form $(\mathbb P^1, 0, 1, \infty, t_1, t_2)$. It should be clear that two such curves $(\mathbb P^1, 0, 1, \infty, t_1, t_2)$ and $(\mathbb P^1, 0, 1, \infty, t'_1, t'_2)$ are isomorphic as marked curves iff $t_1 = t'_1$ and $t_2 = t'_2$, so that $M_{0, 5} = \{ (t_1, t_2) \in M_{0, 4} \mid t_1 \neq t_2\}$. You can generalize this to any $M_{0, n}$ with $n \geq 4$ in a similar manner.

For the compactification you can refer to Proposition 10 in these [lecture notes](https://anddil.github.io/_pages/CohFT/Lecture1.pdf) by A. Di Lorenzo. The space $\overline{M}_{0, n}$ is the universal family $\overline{U}_{0, n - 1}$ over $\overline{M}_{0, n-1}$. In your specific case, we have that $\overline{M}_{0, 5}$ is the blow-up of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ at the points $(0, 0)$, $(1, 1)$ and $(\infty, \infty)$.

Judging by your comment, you seem to be interested in cohomology of stable curves. [This paper](https://www.hse.ru/data/2014/11/13/1101420183/2013.04.03.pdf) by D. Zvovinke might be interesting. In particular, you can find the same argument for the universal curve of $\overline{M}_{0, 4}$ in Example 1.47.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will look at the link you provided.